# Is Django admin functionality used in production on large sites or do you use it for testing only?

Tags: django, user-interface, django-admin, user-experience

I have been working through the Django tutorial and I note on page 7...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial07/

...that the much touted "admin for free" feature of Django is rather weak. The tutorial shows how to add Choice objects to Question objects in the Polls admin. Three Choices are added by the `ChoiceInline` class, but the problem is that none of those three may be removed. Only Choices added by clicking the Add button may be removed. This is poor UI/UX because it mixes static and dynamic behaviour in an arbitrary way. It doesn't look so bad in the tutorial example, but if the feature is deployed thoroughly, it can result in new Question objects having three Choices (or however many are specified) that cannot be deleted. One solution is to use no Choices by default and only use the Add button, but that is not good either, as there should be at least one Choice object by default, or rather two of them, since we're working on a Poll. But the fields should all have the same functionality, they should all be removable.

Having seen this, my question for those experienced in working with Django on large projects: Is the "admin for free" feature used in production? Or would it be wiser to "roll your own" instead of trying to find workarounds for the weaknesses? I've identified one weakness, perhaps there are others.

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect, there are no undeletable choices and no risk of three extra ones being created.

Comment: @DanielRoseman From the tutorial page linked to in my question: 'At the end of the three current slots you will find an “Add another Choice” link. If you click on it, a new slot will be added. If you want to remove the added slot, you can click on the X to the top right of the added slot. Note that you can’t remove the original three slots.'

Comment: But they're *slots* where you can create choices, not actual choices. You just get three slots by default and can add more if you like. Even that default number is configurable.

Comment: There is some confusion in terminology then, because "Add another Choice" that the tutorial refers to, also adds another slot. But that slot can be deleted while the default ones can't. Call it whatever you like, but the duality in functionality is there.

Comment: Why the downvote? My question is valid and the problem admitted in the tutorial, though not stated as a problem there. That is my own evaluation from experience of good UI/UX.

Answer (score 0):

It is excellent in all environments.  The functionality is there is not explained in your tutorial.  For example, if you want at least 3 answers within the TabularInline you would specify `min_num = 3`

Comment: The `TabularInline` declaration highlights the problem even more. Please see the page I linked to. It is explained on the page: 'Note that there is an extra “Delete?” column that allows removing rows added using the “Add Another Choice” button and rows that have already been saved.' But not rows that were added with `TabularInline`. So you get the Delete column but aren't able to delete all rows.